# Cannot install Visual Studio Code on Debian Linux (i86)

Tags: debian, visual-studio-code

I only see links for amd64 packages for Visual Studio Code. My own processor is i386/i686, Intel.
On trying to install the amd .deb package, I get

```
dpkg: error processing archive code_1.59.0-1628120042_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 code_1.59.0-1628120042_amd64.deb
```

Does this mean you need to have AMD chips to run Visual Studio Code? There is no other way?

System is debian jessie.

Comment: You are trying to install an 64bit software on a 32bit OS, that will not work. Visual Studio Code does only support 64bit Linux, therefore you can't use VSC unless you reinstall your OS with a 64bit Linux version.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.